# Rails product catalog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

noob question here :)

I´m trying to setup a product catalog in rails 4 using gems devise and shoppe. Shoppe for products and categories management. Check it here http://tryshoppe.com/

### Requirements:

Users should be able to create catalogs of products.
One user has many catalogs and one catalog has one user.
One catalog has many products and on product has many catalogs

## Model Specs

Here´s my model outside Shoppe Engine namespace.

### User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :catalogs
  has_many :products, through: :catalogs
  attr_accessor :products
end
```

### Catalog

```
class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product, class_name: 'Shoppe::Product'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

### Product

Inside Shoppe namespace, just show relevant part.

```
module Shoppe
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Catalogs which are associated with this product
    has_many :catalogs
    has_many :users, class_name: 'User', through: :catalogs
  end
end
```

I´m trying to setup a has many through associations between users and products through catalogs. But i´m not sure if this is the correct way for the results I need.

Maybe I need to create another join table between Catalogs and Products?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? How will a catalog actually work?

Comment: Simple functions: Show list of catalogs per user, show list of products inside catalog, edit catalog name, add and remove products inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need another join table; only many-to-many relationship needs join table. In one-to-many (product-to-catalog) relationship, ActiveRecord just record the id in one of the table (`product_id` in `CATALOG` table). Normally in many-to-many (user-to-catalog) relationship you do need a join table, but in your case the `CATALOG` table actually *works as* a join table, since it has both `product_id` and `user_id`.

In other cases, says, if you did not like to create a `Catalog` class, you can call `has_and_belongs_to_many` then the products and users could have a list of each other. However, in this case, you *do* need a join table.

Check out the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for better understanding (and great relationship diagram).

### Edit

Seems like the OP wants a one-to-many relationship between user and catalogs, and a many-to-many relationship between catalogs and products. Then a join table between catalogs and products would be necessary.

It is strongly recommended to create migration with [generator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration)

```
bin/rails g migration CreateJoinTableCatalogProduct catalog product
```

as it creates a migration with `create_join_table` instead of less informative `create_table`.

Comment: Maybe I need to explain it better. **It´s exactly the opposite as you say**. A user can have one or many catalogs. A catalog can have one or many products inside. A product can belong to none or many catalogs.

Comment: @EnriqueGallart Note that if you want to "show list of catalogs per user", you should have a `user_id` in `CATALOG` instead of a `catalog_id` in `USER` (where a single user can have only one catalog).

Comment: @EnriqueGallart A catalog can have one or many product inside? Then I guess having "product *has_namy* catalogs" is not appropriate. Instead, it should be a "catalog *has_many* products".

Comment: Thanks. That´s correct. So I guess I need another relation between catalogs and products? Maybe a many-to-many (Catalogs-Products)?

Comment: Yes, if it is a many-to-many relationship. Then you need a join table [`:products_catalogs`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations). Besides, it is strongly recommended to create migration with [generator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration): `bin/rails g migration CreateJoinTableCatalogProduct catalog product`

Comment: @EnriqueGallart Forgot to notify you in previous comment. The benefit of the generator includes that it creates a migration with `create_join_table` instead of less informative `create_table`.